# Entity Framework code first DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework code-first with migrations. Works great but I would like all SQL Server tables created to have the `DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE` option.

What would be the best approach to do that?

Comment: It seems you can specify compression for the indexes at least: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverindexbuilderextensions.usedatacompression?view=efcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserverindexbuilderextensions-usedatacompression(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-indexbuilder-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-datacompressiontype) Maybe something like that will work for you?

Comment: It's very unlikely that all tables benefit from page compression. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: @GertArnold lets say that one would. How to do it in a good way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with with a [Custom Migration Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations) that rebuilds the selected tables with page compression, eg

```
ALTER TABLE [Whatever] REBUILD WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
```